# newcommand in tcolorbox

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I am useing a lot of tcolorboxes and i would like to set them up with newcommand in order to save time.

I use

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced jigsaw]
        test test
    \end{tcolorbox}
```

I would like to replace

```
[breakable, enhanced jigsaw]
```

with something like

```
\newcommand{\help}{breakable, enhanced jigsaw}
-->
\begin{tcolorbox}[\help]
        test test
    \end{tcolorbox}
```

but it is not working.
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can make macros work, this will defeat the purpose (in my opinion). I recommend using styles instead, they are made for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced jigsaw]
        test test
\end{tcolorbox} 

\tcbset{help/.style={breakable, enhanced jigsaw}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[help]
        test test
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

You can make macros work by copying the `style` key from `tikz` to `tcolorbox`, and using it with the `/.expanded` key handler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\pgfkeys{/tcb/style/.style=#1}%
% adapted from 
% \pgfkeys{/tikz/style/.style=#1}%
% in tikz.code.tex
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced jigsaw]
        test test
\end{tcolorbox} 


\newcommand{\help}{breakable, enhanced jigsaw}
\begin{tcolorbox}[style/.expanded=\help]
        test test
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

Both codes yield

[image]

but I find the first option, i.e. second box in the first code, more appropriate.